# Why is BigQuery converting some dates to timestamps but not others?

Tags: sql, timestamp, google-bigquery

Our SQL query shown below is converting strings to timestamp fields but failing on some dates and not on others. What is causing this conversion to fail?

```
SELECT birthdate, TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(birthdate, r'(..)/(..)/(....)', r'\3-\2-\1')) ts
FROM [our_project:our_table] LIMIT 1000
```

Here are the results. Notice that BigQuery is giving "null" for many of the dates. Why is the regex failing? Is there something to add to make it more robust?

[image: sql results]

Here is a second conversion query we tried.

```
SELECT birthdate, TIMESTAMP(year + '-' + month + '-' + day) as output_timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT 
    birthdate, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(birthdate, '.*/([0-9]{4})$') as year, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(birthdate, '^([0-9]{2}).*') as day, 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(birthdate, '.*/([0-9]{2})/.*') AS month 
  FROM 
    [our_project:our_table]
)
LIMIT 1000
```

Notice that nulls appeared in these results as well.

[image: sql_query2]

How might we fix what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the month and the day were swapped (international versus U.S.) The result is that the ranges were invalid for the timestamp. Once we swapped the day and the month - then the conversions occurred without problems.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use American date formats in data!

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're not using the supported [TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) data type?

From the docs:

> You can describe TIMESTAMP data types as either UNIX timestamps or calendar datetimes.

Datetimes need to be in a specific format:

> A date and time string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. The UTC and Z specifiers are supported.

This would also make it easier to query this particular column, as it would allow you to leverage BigQuery's standard SQL dialect. Commands such as [HOUR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#hour), DAYOFWEEK, DAYOFYEAR, etc.

Here's an example query using one of BQ's public datasets to find the most popular pickup hour using a timestamp field:

```
SELECT
  HOUR(pickup_datetime) as pickup_hour, 
  COUNT(*) as pickup_count
FROM
  [nyc-tlc:green.trips_2014]
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY 
  pickup_count DESC
```

will yield:

```
Row pickup_hour pickup_count     
1   19  1059068  
2   18  1051326  
3   20  985664   
4   17  957583   
5   21  938378   
6   22  908296
```

Comment: We do want to use TIMESTAMP. The aim of the question is that we were trying to convert a column of type "STRING" to "TIMESTAMP" but that conversion was failing. We fixed it by taking the approach as noted.

Comment: I see, I see. It may be less effort to have the source data formatted to a valid TIMESTAMP format prior to loading into BQ, rather than transforming the column once it's already inside BQ (if you have control over that process).

Answer (score 1):

If your data has custom formatting of timestamps, you can always use PARSE_TIMESTAMP function in Standard (non-legacy) SQL - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#parse_timestamp
I.e. all the following queries

```
select parse_timestamp("%Y-%d-%m", x) from
unnest(["2016-31-12", "1999-01-02"]) x

select parse_timestamp("%Y-%d-%m", x) from
unnest(["2016-31-12", "1999-01-02"]) x

select parse_timestamp("%Y-%b-%d", x) from
unnest(["2016-Dec-31", "1999-Feb-01"]) x
```

results in

```
f0_  
1   2016-12-31 00:00:00 UTC  
2   1999-02-01 00:00:00 UTC
```